# Is it possible to estimate the average visitor duration given data for amount of exits/entries?

Tags: database, statistics

I've made some software for someone to keep track of how many people are currently inside an attraction. When someone enters or leaves, I get an entry in my database marking this event. Without keeping track of individuals, is it possible to estimate the average visitor duration to this attraction with just the data I have?

An example portion of the data I have spanning five minutes between 12:00 and 12:05 looks like this:

```
+----------+-----+-----+
| Time     | In  | Out |
+----------+-----+-----+
| 12:00:00 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:01:04 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:01:05 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:01:05 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:01:06 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:01:13 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:01:13 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:01:14 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:01:14 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:02:56 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:02:56 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:02:56 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:02:56 |   0 |   1 |
| 12:04:13 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:04:13 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:04:14 |   1 |   0 |
| 12:04:14 |   1 |   0 |
+----------+-----+-----+
```

At the start of the day there are no people in the attraction, so the above data is enough to calculate how many people are inside at a given time. Is there also enough information to estimate how long inside the average visitor spends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is sufficient data, but there are some issues you should be aware of.

Suppose you have 2 visitors. Visitor 1 enters at 12:00 and exits at 12:30 (30 minutes), while visitor 2 enters at 12:20 and exits and 13:20 (60 minutes). The average duration of visit is 45 minutes ((30+60)/2).

You do not actually have to know which exit corresponds to which entry. If you get them mixed up you would have visitor 1 entering at 12:00 and exiting at 13:20 (80 min) and visitor 2 entering at 12:20 and exiting at 12:30 (10 min)... but the average is still 45 minutes ((80+10)/2).

**So the first solution could be to:**

- just match any entry with any exit
- calculate the visit duration
- average all the durations of the day

But this may pose a problem if some visitor entered or exited without your database being updated correctly. In this case you will have some extra entries or exits you are not able to match. And unless you match entries and exits randomly, you'll probably skew the calculation a bit.

**Another better way to calculate the same average is to:**

- calculate the average time of all entries
- calculate the average time of all exits
- calculate the difference between the above

With the sample data I provided above you will get average time of entry 12:10 ((12:00+12:20)/2), average time of exit 12:55 ((12:30+13:20)/2). Average time of visit 0:45 (12:55-12:10)... same as method 1.

**This second method is better because it is not skewed by unmatched data. It does represent the best estimate you can calculate with the data provided even if the data is not perfect.**

**If the data is good (perfectly matches what happened in real life, with every single entry and exit being registered correctly), then both solutions are mathematically accurate and provide the same result.**

Comment: Thanks, I quite like your second solution and it seems pretty obvious now that I think about it! In your introduction, are you saying that, even if I knew when each individual entered and left and calculated the average visitor duration, it would still be the same value? So I don't need to know the individual visiting durations?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The math behinds guarantees you really don't have to know which visitor entered or left... the result is the same. The second answer is also more easy to implement, as it can be done with a simple SQL statement, like Fernando has shown.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, I think you don't have information enough, because you cannot pair the "exits" whith the "incomes". But, to have an overall aproach, I think you can simply calculate:

```
(SELECT SUM(IF(out=1,time,0))) - SELECT (SUM(IF(in=1,time,0))) / SELECT count(*)
```

BUT, you MUST ensure that the rows you are taking into account are paired (same outputs than inputs).

It's a little bit tricky, but I hope it can work...